# Background image in constraints layout does not work

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my app to use a image in the background for signup and signin function. I am using android studio 2.3 and so far I can see that lot many things have changed since last year. Where we used relative or linearlayout now that is constraint layout. I included a code with the root layout as:

```
android:background="@drawable/wallpaper_2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
```

Check this image for more information:
[image]

[image]

When I test this app on my Nexus 5 it does not show anything just a blank screen but the it shows the same image on the preview screen. Any help would be appreciated on this.

Comment: check logcat warning if it shows Bitmap is too large. in nexus 5 large image not rendering.

Comment: Are you sure the image is not just loading? Setting background this way can make your app slow.

Comment: Set a window background in your theme and apply it to relevant activity. that should avoid overdraw atleast

Comment: app.example.com.signin W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3240x5760, max=4096x4096). This is the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resolution of your image is too large for the device [resize](http://www.picresize.com/) your picture to smaller dimesions and based on that put your image into specific drawable folder. e.g : If image size is `1280 x 720` than put image in drawable-xxhdpi folder.

Comment: So by just creating drawable-xxhdpi folder and copying the image to it will downscale it?

Comment: No it wont!  you have to resize it first with the link i have provided, than copy and paste it in your drawable. i dont see a drawable-xxhdpi folder here so you could copy it to mipmap-xxhdpi . the folders are for different screen resolutions.

Comment: i can make your image of a smaller resolution if you can provide me with a link of the image .

Answer (score 2):

To prevent Bitmap too large error, you can simply use libraries like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). These libraries take care of all memory handling

Comment: I don't know how to use that exactly for what I want to achieve but thanks anyways.

Comment: He is just putting an image as a background. The purpose of the libraries are to take scale down image and image processing for multiple images. Its an overkill to use glide or picasso just for one setting a background image.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple option to work around

1- Change

```
   android:background="@drawable/wallpaper_2"
```

To

```
   android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
```

numbers are not allowed in drawable names.

2- check image size if its too large replace it with a smaller sized image.

3- You can add `android:largheap="true"` in application tag in case image is large in resolution

4- Add a relative layout inside constraint layout or replace constraint layout with relative layout and then apply background

Comment: i never had problems applying a background if have checked these 4 things given in the answers. test it hope this will work

Comment: Point number 3 , this will be added in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: It doesn't seem to work tried every step. Do you have any other alternative?

Comment: change image and try again

Answer (score 1):

firstly create all drawable file version for each dpi size

drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhdpi

then put your image by right click on res file and then chose image assert. after this step it will work i think

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 paste the image into the workspace -> project name-> app-> src-> main -> res -> drawable. This worked for me instead only pasting directly into Android Studio 3.1.3 app -> res -> drawable