# No Activity found to handle Intent { }

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

On my **weather app**, the splash screen runs well but when it's getting into the `HomeActivity`, it displays `app has stopped` **when I tested it on my device**

on the `logcat`, it displays:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent {  }
```

Meanwhile I passed intent in my splash screen:

```
        int SPLASH_SCREEN = 5000;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_SCREEN);
    }
}
```

My HomeActivity code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    public static int count=0;
    int[] drawable =new int[]{R.drawable.burj_khalifa,R.drawable.central_bank_of_nigeria,R.drawable.eiffel_tower,R.drawable.hong_kong,R.drawable.statue_of_liberty};
    Timer _t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.burj_khalifa);
            _t = new Timer();
            _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                        public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { // run on ui thread
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (count < drawable.length) {

                                constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(drawable[count]);
                                count = (count + 1) % drawable.length;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
        }, 5000, 5000);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tex.lightweatherforecast">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/burj_khalifa"
    tools:context=".Activity.HomeActivity">


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is there anything to correct this?

Comment: can you register this activity to manifest file

Comment: i dont know how to do that but my manifest is currently no showing any error

Comment: I hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/9158093/9346054

Comment: you create a activity going to menu or you just copy and paste the code

Comment: didn't fix @Ticherhaz, I will post the manifest up

Comment: i created the activity @JAYKuMaR

Comment: try to remove `finish();`

Comment: now it shows a different error in run log: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference @zain

Comment: @Chinez that could be another issue .. can you share where do you `setBackgroundResource` ?

Comment: please check up on my HomeActivity class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225252/discussion-between-chinez-and-zain).

Comment: it is @princeali, the splash screen is the main activity then I have a home activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, removing `finish();` from inside your handler will solve this

```
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();
           }
       }, SPLASH_SCREEN);
```

If you want to remove the splash screen from the stack, then you could do

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference

Now you've in the HomeActivity `onCreate`, and this is different from `No Activity found to handle Intent { }` Error.

this tells that your `constraintLayout` in below statement is null and you can't call `setBackgroundResource` unless you intialize it with a non-null value

```
 constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.burj_khalifa);
```

You got it from your activity layout, you need to check that this id `R.id.layout` actually exists in `activity_home.xml` layout as a first troubleshoot step

```
 constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

Comment: The major issue now is the constraintlayout and I don't know how to check that R.id.layout exists in activity_home.xml layout but I'll post the code up

Comment: Your activity layout doesn't have a layout id.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this was the bug that caused this error since! Thanks for your help guys, it finally fixed after I added the id.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest try writing only .HomeActivity instead of .Activity.HomeActivity
Moreover if it still shows error than I think you cannot write 'R.id.layout'  just because 'layout'  is a keyword so try defining any other id to your constraint layout.

Comment: I've done that before, it didn't fix because my home activity is in a different package .Activity

Comment: I have updated my answer, now you can check it out.

Comment: what id do you suggest i try?

Comment: Any thing else but not 'layout'

Comment: didn't work: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446661/background-image-in-constraints-layout-does-not-work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225255/discussion-between-jamal-and-chinez).